# Expected getter for property [tempLocation] to be marked with @default on all

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to execute a Dataflow pipeline that writes to BigQuery. I understand that in order to do so, I need to specify a GCS temp location.

So I defined options:

```java
private interface Options extends PipelineOptions {
    @Description("GCS temp location to store temp files.")
    @Default.String(GCS_TEMP_LOCATION)
    @Validation.Required
    String getTempLocation();
    void setTempLocation(String value); 

    @Description("BigQuery table to write to, specified as "
                + "<project_id>:<dataset_id>.<table_id>. The dataset must already exist.")
    @Default.String(BIGQUERY_OUTPUT_TABLE)
    @Validation.Required
    String getOutput();
    void setOutput(String value);
}
```

And try to pass this to the `Pipeline.Create()` function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class));
    ...
}
```

But I am getting the following error. I don't understand why because I annotate `with@Default`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected getter for property [tempLocation] to be marked with @Default on all [my.gcp.dataflow.StarterPipeline$Options, org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions], found only on [my.gcp.dataflow.StarterPipeline$Options]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the above snippet your code or a copy from the SDK?

You don't define a new options class for this. You actually want to call withCustomGcsTempLocation on BigQueryIO.Write [1].

Also, I think BQ should determine a temp location on it's own if you do not provide one. Have you tried without setting this? Did you get an error?

[1] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a17478c2ee11b1d7a8eba58da5ce385d73c6dbbc/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L1402

Most users simply set the staging directory. To set the staging directory, you want to do something like:

```
DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create()
    .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
options.setRunner(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);
options.setStagingLocation("gs://SET-YOUR-BUCKET-NAME-HERE");
```

However if you want to set gcpTemporaryDirectory, you can do that as well:

```
GcpOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(GcpOptions.class);
options.setGcpTempLocation()
```

Basically you have to do .as(X.class) to get to the X options. Then once you have that object you can just set any options that are part of X. You can find many additional examples online.

Comment: I tried to adapt a code from the SDK. I basically change the name of the interface to "Options" and added the tempLocation related methods. For the moment I removed the tempLocation related methods and enters the tempLocation as en argument. How can I set the BQ default temp location?

Comment: Just adding an option will not work. You would have to use that option in the right place. You don't need to set up your own options (the option is already an available one). I provided the code call you need to call to set the location in the answer. It's not in options but instead on the Write itself.

Comment: Are you trying to set the general temp location or one specific to the bigquery?

Comment: I am really new to Dataflow so excuse me in advance if my answers are not clear or off-topic. I guess I am trying to set the general temp location as the pipeline executes only if a specify the `tempLocation` in the `org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions` in the Pipeline Arguments from the Run Configuration window of Eclipse.

Comment: Ah okay, that one is just a temporary directory and is not related to BigQuery (though BigQuery may use it if you do not specify a separate one).

Let me append to the answer.

Comment: Added code snippets of how to set the staging directory and the gcs options directory.